# Wallboard not refreshing

Tags: spring-boot-admin

I am running SBA 2.1.3 and my spring boot services are on 2.1.5. Sometimes a service isn't refreshed anymore. If I click the green tile I get a 502 error. The service is down but still green. Also the info isn't refreshed in the wallboard.
What could be causing this?
Logs also not showing any relevant info.

Thx,

Marco

Comment: did you have a look at the browsers console (but it needs to be already opened on page load)

Comment: @joshiste: I get this:

Comment: The connection to http://management-p01.idewe.be/applications was interrupted while the page was loading. sba-core.a6b7e5ec.js:1:173263
Connection to server failed: 
The connection to http://management-p01.idewe.be/applications was interrupted while the page was loading. sba-core.a6b7e5ec.js:1:173263
Connection to server failed: 
error
​
bubbles: false
​
cancelBubble: false
​
cancelable: false
​
composed: false
​
currentTarget: null
​
defaultPrevented: false
​
eventPhase: 0
​

Comment: explicitOriginalTarget: EventSource { url: "http://management-p01.idewe.be/applications", withCredentials: false, readyState: 2, … }
​
isTrusted: true
​
originalTarget: EventSource { url: "http://management-p01.idewe.be/applications", withCredentials: false, readyState: 2, … }
​
target: EventSource { url: "http://management-p01.idewe.be/applications", withCredentials: false, readyState: 2, … }
​
timeStamp: 17913
​
type: "error"

Comment: @joshiste, I have this screenshot:

Comment: https://imgur.com/VHaJBtB

Comment: My service "cobra" has a 502 error but is still green...